# How to insert a list containing alphabets into another list lof list column wise?

Tags: python, list

I go two lists of alphabets

```
headerListOne=['a', 'c', 'g', 'w', 'Q']
```

and another list

```
headerListTwo=['a', 'c', 'w', 'Q', 'front', 'Z']
```

and two lists of lists of numbers:

```
listToCompare=[[9, 0, 2, 7, 0]]
listToCompareTwo=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5]]
```

I want to get an output of:

```
 listToCompare=[[9,a,] [0,c] [2,g] [7,w] [0,Q]]
 listToCompareTwo=[[0,a], [0,c],[0,w], [0,Q], [3,front] [5,z]]
```

Basically I need to reference each number with an alphabet.Tuples are possible too but I prefer list methods because I'm more familiar with them.

Comment: Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
headerListOne=['a', 'c', 'g', 'w', 'Q']
headerListTwo=['a', 'c', 'w', 'Q', 'front', 'Z']
listToCompare=[[9, 0, 2, 7, 0]]
listToCompareTwo=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5]] 
listToCompare = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(listToCompare[0], headerListOne)]
listToCompareTwo = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(listToCompareTwo[0], headerListTwo)]
```

Output:

```
[[9, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [2, 'g'], [7, 'w'], [0, 'Q']]
[[0, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [0, 'Q'], [3, 'front'], [5, 'Z']]
```

Edit:

if you have nested lists, you can try this:

```
listToCompareTwo=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
headerListTwo=['a', 'c', 'w', 'Q', 'front', 'Z']
final_list = [[[a, b] for a, b in zip(i, headerListTwo)] for i in listToCompareTwo]
```

Output:

```
[[[0, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [0, 'Q'], [3, 'front'], [5, 'Z']], [[1, 'a'], [2, 'c'], [3, 'w'], [4, 'Q'], [5, 'front'], [6, 'Z']]]
```

Comment: It works thanks!But it only works if the list of list has one item.Say if listToCompareTwo=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]  it only inserts the alphabets in the first item?How do I make it work for all lists in listToCompareTwo?

Answer (score 0):

Basically we want to combine two lists for which we can use map function. The command would be the following:

```
map(listToCompare, zip(headerListOne, listToCompare))
```

So the output would be:

```
listToCompare=[[9, a], [0, c], [2, g], [7, w] [0, Q]]
```

Answer (score 0):

so I did it only for the first line you just need to change some small stuff to do the second line but here it is:

```
if len(headerListOne) is len(listToCompare):
    for idx, val in enumerate(headerListOne):
        listToCompare[idx]=[listToCompare[idx], val]
```